# "save query" in BigQuery overwrite my old saved query without previous notification

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using Google cloud BigQuery.
I just realized that when I save my query and then I edit / create new query... and then I click save query ... it overwrite my old saved query without any question before.
I hope will be good to popup some message about > ...if I want overwrite my old query.

Comment: is this a question? or you wanted to submit feature request?

Comment: submit request pls

Comment: you can submit your request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162659)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a feature request. Check Mikhail's link above

Comment: @andrew, You can save multiple queries. When you click _"Save query"_ it asks you for the _Name_ and _Visibility_ of the query you are saving. Thus, just change the name for each query that you save, is that what you were seeking clarification for ?

Comment: Hi Alex, I have different experience, when I did  incidentally click Save (and forget click "Save as") it will immediately rewrite my old query

Comment: Anyway  going to raise a ticket for this issue.

Comment: ok, ticket opened.

Comment: @andrew, in BigQuery UI there is one buttom *Save Query* ( next to _run_). I believe It overwrote your previous query because, probably when you clicked _Save Query_ you did not change the name of the query and it was the same as the one you previously saved. Can you check when you click save and change the name of the query if it overwrites the previous one?

Comment: yes, indeed, it works this way, when you didn't change name, it overwrite your last save without any warning, this was my point to this issue how it works.